# How to fetch field revision history for each change, username, created and delta value?

Tags: 7, entities

I would like to fetch and display the revision history for each change for each field attached to an entity.  I notice in each field revision table the username and created are not there. Only the delta value. Is there a way I can display to the user (in a popup over each field) the revision history including the previous values, date changed, and user who changed value.  Possibly using the entity revision itself with a join?

Comment: Yes, exactly as you’ve described should work fine

Comment: you mean this? "Possibly using the entity revision itself with a join?"

Comment: Yup - well, assuming the entity type actually tracks that data; it doesn't have to. If it does, the field name also isn't consistent, even in core. For example it's `revision_uid` for the Node type but `revision_user` for the Media type. You should be able to find out from the entity type's annotation, under `revision_metadata_keys`

Comment: This is Drupal 7